# Running a Mini-ITX Computer with a picoPSU-80 from a power bank possible?

Tags: power-supply, power-bank

To begin, this is related to a project I wanted to do after getting some free hardware from someone. I would like to be able to run this computer from a power bank if possible, although I'm not too experienced at all in hardware. If it is not feasible I would be grateful for an explanation as to why.

Here are the components that need to be discussed

http://resources.mini-box.com/online/PWR-PICOPSU-80/PWR-PICOPSU-80-manual.pdf (PSU DC-DC)

[https://www.amazon.com/Anker-PowerCore-20100mAh-Portable-Delivery/dp/B071WNWRNC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071WNWRNC)
(Powerbank)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07952G6KT/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07952G6KT) 
(USB to 12V 2A DC Connector)

I thought this setup would work as this USB to 12v 2A DC converter should be able to give the PSU what it demands (12v 1A MIN). The end results being however, I get the CPU active heat sink fan to start up for near to a second before it turns off. And then continues to do so if it's left plugged in.

An interesting thing to note is, I have two AC Adapters which are both 12v 2A with the same polarity, one works how it should and one doesn't, which mimics what the powerbank+converter does. The one that doesn't work, doesn't have a ground prong/pin.

Could someone possibly help me out, recommending me some other component(s) to use? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to run a relatively power hungry system off a battery. Why not a NUC or something else more lightweight?

Comment: Mainly, just because I want to play around with the concept for science. The other reason being the casing the computer is in would make a really cool looking set up if I mount a 7inch touchscreen display on it. I also got everything but the converter for free, so it's all in good fun, no 'real' purpose. I'm going to buy a multi-meter to test the amps on both the converter and AC Adapter which isn't working.

Comment: Whether it will work or not depends on the specific computer you're using it to power: that "1A min" just means that the PicoPSU will never draw less than one amp, no matter how small a computer you connect to it.